# Change div value with jQuery not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a masked input I'm trying to build and it works fine in Chrome, only in firefox it doesn't update my text field with the new value...

I receive no console errors neither so I'm unsure what the problem could be?

```
        $('.new-Btn').bind("click", function () {
            $('.html-btn').click();
        });

        $('.html-btn').change(function () {
            var newval = $('.html-btn').val();
            var nvstr = newval.substring(12, 25);
            $('.new-Btn').html(nvstr);
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ykgXG/

Comment: The first 12 chars are remove and if filename is shorter than 12chars you'll get nothing... http://jsfiddle.net/ykgXG/2/

Comment: The problem is that ff doesn't put the prefix used by chrome. If you put away the substring operation in Firefox everything works fine, while in chrome it displays the prefix you're taking away. Dunno if there's a non custom solution

Comment: Thanks @Bernhard - Thats to counter the chrome fakepath, is there another way of preventing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with  browser agents.Some browser displays full path name(chrome,opera,explorer) where as some does not(mozilla).

Here is the code:

```
 var nvstr;
 var newval;

        $('.html-btn').on('change',function () {
             newval = $('.html-btn').val();

           if(!$.browser.mozilla){
            nvstr = newval.substring(12, 25);
            $('.new-Btn').html(nvstr);
           }else{
               alert(11)
            $('.new-Btn').html(newval);
           }
        });
```

Here is a working demo:http://jsfiddle.net/ykgXG/8/

Tested in all the browsers and it works.

Answer (score 0):

u shd use:

```
        $('.new-Btn').bind("click", function () {
            $('.html-btn').trigger('click');
        });

        $('.html-btn').change(function () {
            var newval = $('.html-btn').val();
            var nvstr = newval.substring(12, 25);
            $('.new-Btn').html(nvstr);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

What I am seeing is that your div text changes under Firefox 24. Check what your `substring()` function returns with the file that you're testing it with.

Comment: ahh I see now @Konstantin, I've added that to remove "fakepath"

Answer (score 0):

As my issue was with the fakepathprefix I used an if statement to fun a different function dependant on the browser.

```
if (/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
        $('.new-Btn').bind("click", function () {
            $('.html-btn').trigger('click');
        });

        $('.html-btn').change(function () {
            var newval = $('.html-btn').val();
            var nvstr = newval.substring(12, 25);


            $('.new-Btn').html(nvstr);
        });
} else  {
        $('.new-Btn').bind("click", function () {
            $('.html-btn').trigger('click');
        });

        $('.html-btn').change(function () {
            var newval = $('.html-btn').val();
            $('.new-Btn').html(newval);
        });
}
```